# How to receive mysql query output as list instead of tuple?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, list, mysql-python

I am using the following query to get a list of ids corresponding to the given parameters:

```
userids=[]
sql_select_query = """SELECT userid FROM database1 WHERE username = %s"""
cursor.execute(sql_select_query, (username,))
record = cursor.fetchall()

for row in record:
      userids.append(row)
print(userids)
```

I get a result like:

```
 [('1460871223475326979',), ('1460871240332238850',), ('1460871258518736898',), ('1460871271219085312',), ('1460871286180220941',), ('1460871308963680260',)]
```

I would like to get this result as a list without the brackets, quotes and braces as `1460871223475326979, 1460871240332238850, 1460871258518736898, 1460871271219085312, 1460871286180220941, 1460871286180220941, 1460871308963680260`

I tried the

```
 ",".join(map(str,userids))
```

method, but it only removed the [ ] at the start and end and did nothing for the braces and quotes.

Comment: You can use list comprehension removing the for loop ant doing *userids=[row[0] for row in record]*

Comment: `group_concat` may help you

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

````
You can perform indexing on the list of tuples. All you have to do is,
for row in record:
      userids.append(row[0])
print(userids)
Indexing at zero returns only the first element of each tuple in the list.```
````